# How to get custom attributes in LLVM Pass

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, function-attributes

I implemented a custom attribute in clang as described in the official manual:

[How to add an attribute in Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#how-to-add-an-attribute)

I added a definition to `include/clang/Basic/Attr.td`

```
def attr : InheritableAttr {
  let Spellings = [GCC<"attr">, Declspec<"attr">];
  // FIXME: Does GCC allow this on the function instead?
  let Documentation = [Undocumented];
}
```

and implement the semantic processing of the attribute in `SemaDeclAttr.cpp` by adding a new case.

```
case AttributeList::AT_MyAttr:
   handleSimpleAttribute<MyAttrAttr>(S, D, Attr);
break;
```

After rebuilding clang, it obviously knows the attribute because i don't get an unknown attribute warning when using it.

But I can't get this attribute in LLVM Pass by function `hasFnAttribute()`

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {

            // it didn't work
            if (F.hasFnAttribute("attr")){ 
                  return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

`Attribute::AttrKind` doesn't have `Attribute::attr`. I try to change `/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.td` and some code to make clang run. But it didn't work.

Is there something else i need to consider or what could be the problem?

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391314/clang-custom-attributes-not-visible-in-ast.  I care more about how to use my custom attributes in llvm pass or other scenarios.